# mySQL query select column where value = a or value = b etc

Tags: mysql

How do I write a mysql query so that I can select entries under a column that are equal to resultA or resultB or resultC etc.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = resultA OR WHERE myColumn = resultB OR WHERE myColumn = resultC...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = 'resultA' 
   OR myColumn = 'resultB' 
   OR myColumn = 'resultC';
```

Alternatively,

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN ('resultA', 'resultB', 'resultC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `WHERE` many times, just use `OR` between your conditions

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myColumn = 'resultA'
OR myColumn = 'resultB'
OR myColumn = 'resultC'
```

Note that I surrounded your `resultX` with single quotes assuming they are strings, if they are integers you can omit them

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'resultA' OR myColumn = 'resultB' OR myColumn = 'resultC'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn in (resultA, resultB, resultC ....)
```